# How to center mobile menu title text

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, menu

I have a WordPress website, I have added additional CSS to center the title text of the mobile menu.

```
#mobileMenu_mm1.mobileMenu {
text-align-last: center
}
```

Which works for some devices but apple devices do not show the text centred.

check for yourself [www.aktingalpa.com.au](http://www.aktingalpa.com.au)

iPhones show that the title text is not centred but in the browser and on my android it is centred.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, at least 72.6% of people visiting your site (android) will see it centered ^^

Comment: too bad my client has an iphone lol im so mad.

Comment: @finnmglas Yeah, that’s not the way professional web development works...

Comment: text-align-last isn’t supported in Safari so you’ll have to do something else. Try selecting the last element in the parent container and using standard text-align

Comment: I just had a chance to look at your site now, and I see you are using a `select` or the menu, and it is more difficult to style the options in a select so this changes the question. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a look how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's fine to include a link to the code, but you must also include it in the question itself so when you fix the problem other users with similar issues can still benefit from your question.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Could you give me an example of the type of question to ask? i don't understand how not to use select.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your site and text center issue of the "Navigation" text.
try this CSS :
`{ text-indent: 10px; }`

Comment: This moves the whole button instead of just the text.